# Insert values from an array in a table

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I´m trying to insert all values from an array in different posts in "OrdreDetalierT".
It works fine to write all the values - but I can´t insert it.
The values comes from a checkbox on the previous page.

```
$_SESSION["OrdreID"] = "$last_id";
$Ordre_id = $_SESSION["OrdreID"];

$aId = $_POST['formID'];
if(empty($aId)) 
{
   echo("You havn´t chosen any UVmaterialer.");
} 
else
{
$N = count($aId);

{
echo("You have chosen $N UVmaterialer: ");
for($i=0; $i < $N; $i++)    
echo($aId[$i] . ", ");
}
}

//works as intended
$aId2 = $_POST['formID']; 
for($i=0; $i < $N; $i++)  
echo "FormID" . $aId2[$i] . "<br>";

// This only inserts the last value of the array
$aId3 = $_POST['formID']; 
for($i=0; $i < $N; $i++)  
$sql2 = "INSERT INTO OrdreDetalierT (OrdreID, UVmaterialeID, Antal)
VALUES ('$Ordre_id', '$aId3[$i]', '15')";
```

The value for "Antal"(Number) is inserted just to test.
I hope someone can help, I´m quite new to PHP.

Comment: "It works fine to write all the values" - to write where?

Comment: You are not executing your sql statement

Comment: To write on the page.

Comment: You want to be using complex string syntax. E.g. `"INSERT INTO ... VALUES ( ..., '{$aId3[$i]}'...)` at a guess.

Comment: But it inserts one result in the table - so something is executing.

Comment: Like this?  $aId3 = $_POST['formID']; 
  for($i=0; $i < $N; $i++)  
$sql2 = "INSERT INTO OrdreDetalierT (OrdreID, UVmaterialeID, Antal)
VALUES ('$Ordre_id', '{$aId3[$i]}', '15')";

Comment: What DB library do you use? mysqli or PDO? I wanted to suggest prepared statements.

Comment: I use mysqli as DB library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better use prepared statements inside a loop:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO OrdreDetalierT (OrdreID, UVmaterialeID, Antal) 
                      VALUES (?, ?, ?)";);

$antal = 15;
for($i=0; $i < $N; $i++)  
{
    $stmt->bind_param('isi', $Ordre_id, $aId3[$i], $antal);
    $stmt->execute();
}
$stmt->close();
```

Comment: I get an error: Cannot pass parameter 4 by reference in /customers/b/3/d/kildemarkskolen2.dk/httpd.www/Indkoeb/order.php on line 60  (I suppose it refers to "15")

Comment: @AnnaJohansen You need to assign 15 to a variable and use that.

Comment: Of course. It´s my first time here, where do I accept it?

Comment: @AnnaJohansen Click upon the blank checkmark, and it will become green.